# Do trade policies have to change after Brexit?

Tags: international-trade

Being part of the EU is surely not the only way to participate in a free trade market. Could the UK continue with the same policies despite not being part of the EU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The UK do it the "Norway way" this would mean they are part of the
   European Economic Area, they need to pay into EU budget (roughly 80% of current pay) but
   have no Seat in Brussels)
2. The Switzerland way - bilateral deals and roughly 50% of the
   Norway way costs.
3. Lone Member of WTO.

In any way, Britain would gain the freedom to make its own trade deals (how about TTIP?!).